# VBAT transistor switch is unsymmetrical

Tags: mosfet, lithium-ion, low-battery

Hei,

In relation to my other topic for the [VBAT cutoff circuit](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/312265/rtc-battery-deep-discharge-protection), I have now gotten my hardware back to measure the functionality.

What I have encountered is that the switch-ON is as planned ~2.3V, the transistor kicks the RTC battery to the VBAT pin.

***EDIT***
This is the schematic I have implemented and made measurements on:
(3.3V is NOT present during the measurement, I only applied Battery voltage)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fAf5On.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

BUT

When lowering battery voltage, the transistor switches off at 1.6V (around the voltage at which the STMF091 VBAT circuitry is still functional).
[image: Actual Measurement]

CH1 (Yellow) - PMOS Source aka battery voltage - changed on the power supply.

CH2 (Blue) - PMOS Drain, what the STM's VBAT sees.

**But I can't figure out, how to fix it, so that the transistor also switches OFF at ~2.3V**

I tried to find reasons for such behaviour, so I tried to simulate the capacative load and the switch ON-OFF for the VBAT circuitry (with the transistor model I use on my board).

***EDIT***
I added the capacative load and a switch to simulate the delay for the switch OFF and the behaviour of the VBAT switch for the 3Meg load.
The values there are gorssly experimental, just to get the values I see on the real measurement.

[image: LTSpice simulation of MOSFET cutoff switch]
[**LINK to the LTSpice simulation file**](https://files.fm/u/8xepdsqe) *(sorry, couldn't find a way to upload files here, so added external link (can die soon)*)

Green - Varying source aka battery voltage

Blue - Drain

Red - Load, after the voltage controlled switch.

Cyan - Gate

**Could it really be, that as the load current changes (no load, when turning the transistor ON; and there is still load, when trying to cut off the battery) the thresholds are different ?**

Any ideas if it is because of that and how would I fix the issue?

Comment: Looks like built in hysteresis - switching on and off at the same voltage leads to oscillations/chatter - not good.

Comment: During the time you want to turn off, the source is reverse biased (lower than the drain) and you are discharging your capacitor with current flowing back through the MOSFET.

Comment: Ahh forgot to add the schematic which I have implemented and explained the simulation a bit further.

I added stuff on the simulation, just to get same results as my measurement. No capacitive load is actually present there, nor input and load capacitances - these might be there due to parasitics and also not to make the simulation have convergence issues - so basically I edited the RC load and load current just to get same results on the simulation - but I don't understand Why this occurs OR are my assumptions made in the simulation correct to address the issue.